# How can I update all rows in a table and increment a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database. I need to update a particular column's value but increment it's value at the same time. To explain:

If the table is :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Player]
(
    [PlayerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UnitID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ExerciseID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to go through every row which has an `ExerciseID` of `42C45D73-3FE6-4AFA-8E2F-09BDFC6CBDF7` and update the `Designation` to be `Player - X` but X should start at 1 and increment itself by one every time.

So the first player to be updated would be `Player - 1` the second would be `Player - 2` and so on.

I have no idea where to start with something like this!

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine the first player? Lowest PlayerID? Random? Also, shouldn't X start at 1 and not 0?

Comment: lol, I LOVE your name :)  Update my question to say it should start at 1.  I don't mind which is the first player, it doesn't matter at all, so long as each player has a different name!  I'm just trying to cleanse a DB I have which has about 8m rows... Can't bear to go through them one by one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
; with numbering as (
  select PlayerID,
         UnitID,
         ExerciseID,
         Designation,
         row_number () over (order by PlayerID) - 1 rn
    from Player
   where ExerciseID = '42C45D73-3FE6-4AFA-8E2F-09BDFC6CBDF7'
)
update numbering
   set Designation = 'Player - ' + convert(varchar(10), rn)
```